# Using VBA, I would like to select only those excel sheet cells which have been filled in during the current session. Is this possible?

Tags: vba, excel

Using VBA, I would like to select only those cells which have been filled in during the current session. Is this possible? By current session, I mean upon opening a document.

I am trying to automate an accounting procedure with a single button, which calculates payroll data and automatically updates a .doc file after I have edited an excel spreadsheet.

Comment: I would love to help but honestly Excel has not been designed for the purpose of tracing changes at runtime. You could possibly hook up to an event that's fired when a cell changes and everytime someone changes something write it out to an xml/database but imagine how much overhead you will be adding to end user... Why do you need to track the changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first idea that comes to mind would be to remember the whole document's state on start-up and compare that with the state the document is in, when your single action button is pressed.

Since I don't know how to start a macro on document-opening, you might do it like this:

1. make your whole document read-only
2. provide a button to 'start editing', which is saving the current document's state in a background variable or hidden table sheet and removing the write-protection on the main input sheet(s)
3. let user change whatever needs to be changed
4. provide your 'single button' for the accounting procedure, which is comparing the current document's state with the safed initial state, re-activate the write-protection, clear background variable/hidden sheet, and execute the accounting procedure

I'd probably go with the hidden table sheet, since this is allowing you to collect all changes, even if the file is saved, closed, and reopend before your actual business logic is triggered.

Without any more input on the actual context/data involved, its hard to be more specific. I hope this gives you something to start on.

Comment: You can start macro on document-opening by creating function `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` in ThisWorkbook module.

Comment: Many thanks. Apologies, I will add some more details. At the moment, I input payroll data for employees (hours worked) onto a spreadsheet and then fill in another 'payslip' document. However, I would like to be able to merely input the hours worked and have an automatic payslip produced at the click of a button. The input spreadsheet has previous data which does not need to be on a new payslip. Therefore, I only want to export data updated during the current session.

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood your requirements fully, but it seems you could include some sort of payroll id. ie If you have a static cell which stores the next payroll id, every new row gets assigned this id. When you create the payslip you include everything with this id then increment the static cell.

Comment: Does the generated payslip cover more than one payment period (I.e. month, fortnight, whatever is usual)? If not, you could scan the document for the latest date you have a value for - when the button is pressed - and produce the payslip for the period containing this date. E.g. The last row containing valid data is June 28th when the button was pressed, so produce the payslip for June. No need to track what the user did. This way the user can even repeat the generation if necessary.

Comment: If your payslip is NOT fixed to a certain period, you could include a hidden/write-protected column that contains all the hour values from the last button press to be compared with. After the successful payslip generation, you update those cells accordingly. To avoid having a macro that runs too long, you probably would want a fixed setting (e.g. three months) of how much data before the last inserted data is included in your comparison.